# Dative or nominative?

Tags: grammatical-case, dative, nominative

Can you please tell me which is correct? I can't figure out if it should be dative or nominative:

> A) Wir fahren von Bonn, **die** ehemalige Hauptstadt, nach Berlin.
>
> B) Wir fahren von Bonn, **der** ehemaligen Hauptstadt, nach Berlin.

Similarly:

> A) Ich komme aus Frankfurt, **meine** Geburtsstadt.
>
> B) Ich komme aus Frankfurt, **meiner** Geburtsstadt.

Comment: Answer B is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Der Teil, der zwischen den beiden Kommas steht, ist eine Apposition, also eine Beifügung bzw. ein Erklärungszusatz. Das ist ein Satzglied, das eng mit dem Attribut verwandt ist, sich aber in einigen Details davon unterscheidet.

Es gibt enge und weite Appositionen:

- enge Apposition

  > Wir fahren von *der ehemaligen Hauptstadt* Bonn nach Berlin.
- weite Apposition

  > Wir fahren von Bonn, *der ehemaligen Hauptstadt,* nach Berlin.

Enge Appositionen müssen immer im selben Kasus wie das Bezugsnomen stehen. Bei weiten Appositionen gilt das in der Regel auch, daher ist

> Wir fahren von Bonn, *der ehemaligen Hauptstadt,* nach Berlin.

richtig. Allerdings gibt es eine Ausnahme:

Wenn eine weite Apposition kein Artikelwort (Determinativ) enthält, kann sie stattdessen im Nominativ stehen:

- mit Artikel Kasusübereinstimmung mit dem Bezugswort (hier Genitiv):

  > Die Werke des Künstlers, *eines Briten,* sind beeindruckend.
- ohne Artikel im Nominativ:

  > Die Werke des Künstlers, *Brite,* sind beeindruckend.

Weil sowohl »die« also auch »ehemalige« Determinierer sind, also zugleich weggelassen werden müssten, und weil der Nominativ und der Dativ von »Hauptstadt« gleich sind, kann man hier den Unterschied leider nicht erkennen:

> Wir fahren von Bonn, *Hauptstadt,* nach Berlin.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answers are B) "der ehemaligen Hauptstadt" and B) "meiner Geburtstadt" respectively.

The dative is the the right choice because we are answering where ("woher?") you are coming from.

All the best
Philipp

Comment: The rule is that the case in the attributive phrase ("der ehemaligen Hauptstadt") has to follow the case of the subject ("von Bonn"). Same in: "Dies ist Lieschens, meiner lieben Tante, Garten" - both Genitiv. Also: "Da stieß er dem Poseidon, dem schrecklichen Riesen, den Spieß ins Auge" - both Dativ.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann But what if it is not an attributive phrase but a parethesis?

Answer (score -2):

I would argue that **B is correct and feels much more natural in both cases**, but that A can also be considered correct under certain circumstances.

This would be the case if you considered »die ehemalige Hauptstadt« not as an attributive phrase but as a [rhetoric parenthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parenthesis_(rhetoric)).

This is more obvious in longer parentheses, and when an en-dash is used instead of a comma:

> Wir fahren von Bonn – Bonn die Graue, Bonn die Verregnete, die
>   ehemalige Hauptstadt — nach Berlin.

But while it’s common practice, there is no rule that forces you to use en-dashes: a comma may correctly be used instead:

> Wir fahren von Bonn, Bonn die Graue, Bonn die Verregnete, die
>   ehemalige Hauptstadt, nach Berlin.

And neither is there a rule that tells us about the length of the parenthesis: it can be short.

> Wir fahren von Bonn, die ehemalige Hauptstadt, nach Berlin.

In your example, this is definitely worse than option B, but grammatically speaking, it’s possible.

Comment: I expected down-votes on this answer. I’d be happy to know the reasons though. If my answer is plainly wrong, I’ll gladly delete it!

Comment: Das letzte Beispiel ist halt standardsprachlich nicht richtig. Siehe z.B. http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Satzgliedbau/Nomen/Apposition.html. Auch wenn man das umgangssprachlich manchmal so hört.